# phase estimation from I and Q

Tags: matlab, sampling

let say I have a discrete sine signal. I build the I and Q channel according to sampling with a frequency 4*time the signal frequency. that means multiplying the signal with [1 1 -1 -1.....]. in Matlab:

```
n1=1024;
n=[0:n1-1];
f=50;
sf=4*f;
PHI=150; 
x=(1*sin(2*pi*(f*1e6)*((1/sf)*1e-6)*n+PHI*pi/180));
xx=reshape(x,4,n1/4);
xrr=[xx(1,1:n1/4) ;-xx(3,1:n1/4)];
xii=[xx(2,1:n1/4) ;-xx(4,1:n1/4)];
I=reshape(xrr,1,n1/2);
Q=reshape(xii,1,n1/2);
```

I filtred now the I and Q with a Low pass.

```
PHI=atan2d(Q,I)
```

Why get something different than 150?

Comment: Maybe radians not degrees? It won't be this simple surely?

Comment: I do not think so!

Comment: What did you get that was different?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the 2-argument version of `atan2d`,

`atan2d(I, Q)`,

instead of `atan2d(Q/I)`.

With the one argument form, there's no way to distinguish between the 2nd and 4th quadrants, so you probably got an answer of -30 degrees or something.

*Caveat: I did not test this in Matlab, only in SciLab.*

**Edit** Here is my SciLab code:

```
n1=1024;
n=[0:n1-1];
f=50;
sf=4*f;
PHI=150; 
x=(1*sin(2*%pi*(f*1e6)*((1/sf)*1e-6)*n+PHI*%pi/180));
xx=matrix(x,4,n1/4);
xrr=[xx(1,1:n1/4) ;-xx(3,1:n1/4)];
xii=[xx(2,1:n1/4) ;-xx(4,1:n1/4)];
I=matrix(xrr,1,n1/2);
Q=matrix(xii,1,n1/2);

phi = atan(I, Q) * 180 / %pi;
```

You see this is essentially identical to yours, except

1. SciLab has `matrix` instead of `reshape`.
2. SciLab doesn't have `atan2d`.
3. SciLab uses `%pi` instead of `pi`.

With this code I get 150 in all elements of the `phi` array.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i correct this in the code. but i still get the wrong phase. i get -1.0158. in degree it is  -1.0158*180/pi. i should get the 150, or not?

Comment: @dspp, I don't have Matlab available to test your code, but with minor changes and using the two-argument form of atan2, SciLab gives me 150 degrees as excpected.

Comment: Maybe you have the order of arguments reversed in your atan2 call?